# java multithreaded hashed ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I want to do a hash on every item from an arraylist and basically return it on the main. But for example a have this:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class hash extends Thread {

    private Thread t = null;
    private MessageDigest md = null;
    private StringBuffer sb = null;
    private String message = null;
    private ArrayList<String> list = null;
    private int count = 0;

    public hash(ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public final void mdstart() {

        for(String item:list){
            this.message=item;
            if(t==null){
                t = new Thread(this);
                t.start();
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("end: "+this.count);

    }

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        System.out.println("run: "+this.count);
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(this.message.getBytes());

            byte[] digest = md.digest();
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (byte hash : digest) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02x", hash));
            }
            System.out.println(this.message + " : " + sb.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            System.out.println("no such algorithm exception : md5");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add("message" + i);
        }
        new hash(list).mdstart();      
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
end: 10
run: 10
message9 : 99f72d2de922c1f14b0ba5e145f06544
```

which means that the program run only the last one thread from those I expect.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your Thread in `t`, which is null at the start but after creating the first Thread, it isn't null anymore, thus your if fails and no new Thread is created. Then you try to modify the message while this Thread runs... Honestely, the whole thing is a mess. Even if you were to create 10 Threads, they would all point to the same hash() object where the message variable is changing randomly without knowing if any Thread has already finished working.

For example, the following could happen:

1. You start the Thread for first message
2. Thread has not yet run, but your for loop already sets the message to the 2nd one
3. The thread runs and calculates the message for the 2nd message
4. Message 3 is set. Nothing happens since Thread is already finished.
5. Message 4 is set, again, nothing happens as the Thread is done 
   etc.

To fix it:

- Remove the list variable from hash.
- Create a new hash() object for each hashcode/message
- Start a new thread for each hash() object. Then it should work.

Comment: I'd also add changing the parent of the `hash` class to `Runnable` rather than `Thread` as it is never used as a `Thread` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code will start only one thread:

```
if(t==null){
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}
```

Once the first thread is started, `t` is no longer `null`, so no new threads would be created.

To fix this problem, make an array of threads, and set `threads[count++]` to the newly created thread in your loop. Once the loop is over, you can `join` your threads to make sure they all finish before `mdstart()` returns:

```
public final void mdstart() {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[list.size()];
    for(String item:list){
        this.message=item;
        threads[count] = new Thread(this);
        threads[count].start();
        count++;
    }
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
    System.out.println("end: "+this.count);
}
```

**Note:** This will fix the start-up portion of your code. You would need to deal with synchronization issues in your `run()` method to complete the fix.

Comment: I doubt this will help, since he is changing the message in `this` quite randomly and all the Threads would access the same `this` object...

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Absolutely - this will only ensure that ten threads get started. It wouldn't address OP's synchronization issues.

Comment: Thanks for yours help, i understand some serious mistakes i've done. Could you recommend me some link to read more about threads?

Comment: @sifis I can't think of a good book or a tutorial, apart from the Oracle-supplied one ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)), but you probably worked your way through it already.